# Way to configure hostname from jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have my own machine with IP ex) `198.123.456.789`.
And I want to map this IP to `myown.test.com`.

In Jenkins, without changing machine's `/etc/hosts` file(Ubuntu), 
how can I configure/use `myown.test.com` instead of IP `198.123.456.789`?

Comment: Hi. This has nothing to do with Jenkins, but is about [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). Please ask the administrator of your domain `test.com`.

Comment: Ok. With changing `/etc/resolv.conf` I can connect to `myown.test.com`. It might not be possible to configure Jenkins itself as your comment.

Comment: But changing it on your local machine only changes it for you. I assume that this is not what you want. If you also want it for your colleagues, then you have to change DNS entries. That's how the Internet works.